# VBA Excel: Copying new data to lastrow + 1 of previous dataset

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am currently working on an Excel macro where I take data from one worksheet (sheet1) to another (sheet2) which is currently already working. However, I want to make sure that if data is changed in sheet1 (for example when a new reporting quarter starts), the new data is not copied over existing data, but below it.

I currently have the following code which only copies the data based on a specific value ("accruals Q3 - 2023"). With the green comments, I tried to copy the data to the lastrow + 1, which does not work efficiently.

See the following code:

```vb
Sub Accruals()

    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim LastRowCopy As Long
    Dim LastRowDest As Long
    
        Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    LastRowCopy = wsCopy.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowDest = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    j = 1
    
    For i = 1 To LastRowCopy
        If wsCopy.Cells(i, 9).Value = "Accrual Q3 2023 - " Then
            
            wsCopy.Rows(i).Copy
            wsDest.Rows(j + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            
            
            'wsCopy.Rows(i).Range("A2:K" & LastRowCopy).Copy
            'wsDest.Rows(j).Range("A" & LastRowDest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
      
End Sub
```

A different question I struggle with, is the data I copy based on the restriction "Accrual Q3 2023 - ". Currently, only variables with this exact text is selected. However, I wonder wether it's possible to make this restriction where the first few letters can be specified instead of the whole text. In normal Excel, one would use the Left function for this. Is this also possible in a VBA?

I would appreciate it to receive input on my two struggles.

I tried various ways to copy the data to after the last row of the current data. Moreover, I watched a lot of youtube video's.

Comment: No need for `j` use `wsDest.Rows(LastRowDest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` and then `LastRowDest = LastRowDest + 1`. You can use `Left()` but easier might be `If wsCopy.Cells(i, 9).Value Like "Accrual*" Then` * is any text.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try this:

```
Sub Accruals()

    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim LastRowCopy As Long
    Dim LastRowDest As Long
    
        Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    LastRowCopy = wsCopy.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowDest = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row        'modified
    
    j = 1
    
    For i = 1 To LastRowCopy
        If wsCopy.Cells(i, 9).Value = "Accrual Q3 2023 - " Then
            
            wsCopy.Rows(i).Copy
            wsDest.Rows(LastRowDest + j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'modified
            
            
            'wsCopy.Rows(i).Range("A2:K" & LastRowCopy).Copy
            'wsDest.Rows(j).Range("A" & LastRowDest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
      
End Sub
```

The Left function can be used also in VBA.  [Microsoft Left function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/left-leftb-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very kindly!